# Python TypeError: 'float' object is not callable - Using @property decorator, abstract classes, and super()

Tags: python, python-decorators, super, abc

I created a short code to learn a bit more about abstract classes and the getter decorator in python as well as `super`. Here is my code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Abstract_class(ABC):
    
    @abstractmethod    
    def cal(self):
        pass        
        
class Sub_class1(Abstract_class):
    
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        super().__init__()
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
        
    @property#remove to make it work
    def cal(self):
        return ( (self.num1/100) * self.num2 ) + 50
        
        
class Sub_class2(Sub_class1):
    def __init__(self, num1, num2, num3):
        super().__init__(num1, num2)
        self.num3 = num3

        

class Sub_class3(Sub_class2):
  
    def Real_num3(self):

        valor = super().cal()
        r_num3 = (valor**2) + (self.num3/100)
        return r_num3
     

x = Sub_class3( 80, 120, 10000
print( x.Real_num3() )
```

The code as it was stated shows me the error: `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable`. I figured out that by removing the `@property` decorator in `Sub_class1` my problem was solved.

I assuming here that it is not possible to use `super` along with `@property` decorator.

Now, I am not an expert and as I said before, I am trying to get my head around this topic.

My question is why I've got that error when using the decorator `@property` and `super`? Why this is not possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean: `valor = self.cal`? The `super()` here is redundant, and since `cal` is a property, you don't need to call it.  (btw `Sub_class1` doesn't need the call to `super().__init__()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After decorating a function with `@property`, you no longer call it but instead use `.cal` to access it (remove the parenthesis).

Answer (score 0):

Your Sub_class3 can be as follows:

```
class Sub_class3(Sub_class2):

    def Real_num3(self):
        valor = super().cal   # cal is a property not method - you use a @property decorator to change that method to property
        r_num3 = (valor ** 2) + (self.num3 / 100)
        return r_num3
```