# Im having "TypeError: 'float' object is not callable" error. Plz anybody who can help. "Thanks"

Tags: python, setter, callable

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary, increment):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.increment = increment

    @property
    def salaryafterIncre(self):
        return self.salary * (1+self.increment)
    
    @salaryafterIncre.setter
    def salaryafterIncre(self):
        self.salary = self.salary * (1+self.increment)

e1 = Employee("shubh", 10000, 0.1)
print(e1.salaryafterIncre)
e1.salaryafterIncre()
print(e1.salary)
```

Comment: If you marked method with `@property` you should not call it with `()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python TypeError: 'float' object is not callable - Using @property decorator, abstract classes, and super()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73925821/python-typeerror-float-object-is-not-callable-using-property-decorator-ab)

Answer (score 0):

When you access the property you don't treat it as callable in python.

In your case `e1.salaryafterIncre()` is causing the problem. Change it to `e1.salaryafterIncre`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value with property.setter and keep that value in a variable inside the **init** function, you shouldn't give the imported value directly to salary in the **init** function.

Property does what you want and outputs it, but the value of salary doesn't change. The value of salary is the value it gets from outside. You can replace it with a non-property function and keep the value you changed.

If you give salary a random value and pass the imported value to property.setter function. property.setter does what you want and changes the value you hold in the **init** function and stores that value.

that is, if we want to replace a value in the init function with a property. you should not equate it to an external value inside the init function.

**the code has been updated to do the action you specified,
you can try this;**

```
   class Employee:
    
    def __init__(self,name, salary, increment):
        self.salary = 0
        self.name = name
        self.increment = increment

    
    @property
    def salaryafterIncre(self):
        return self.salary
    
    @salaryafterIncre.setter
    def salaryafterIncre(self,salary):
        self.salary = self.salary+ salary * (1+self.increment)

e1 = Employee("shubh", 10000, 0.1)
e1.salaryafterIncre = 10000
print(e1.salary)
e1.salaryafterIncre = 10000
print(e1.salary)
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this line has zero effect anyway and can be removed altogether just as well.

Comment: Thanks for helping. im what here trying to do is change the value of e1.salary to 11000.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm keeping this answer basic -- this may be an oversimplification but is good enough for what you're doing).

By marking `salaryafterIncre` with `@property`, you've turned it into something that behaves a lot like a variable, rather than a method.

So when you write `e1.salaryafterIncre`, this actually already returns the value of this salary, which is a variable of type `float`. By adding `()` to this, you're attempting the call this floating point number as a function, which doesn't make sense! So just leave out the `()` when interacting with this property.

**Edit**: So the property function,

```
@property
    def salaryafterIncre(self):
        return self.salary * (1+self.increment)
```

does make sense as you've currently written it. The line `print(e1.salaryafterIncre)` would print (1 + increment)*salary.

However your setter doesn't make sense. A setter should take a value, and then update a variable with that value. A use case might be, perhaps you want some event to fire off every time the variable is updated, so you make it a property and fire that event off in the function. Or maybe other things depend on this variable and need to be recomputed when its value changes.

What you have instead is a setter which takes no arguments (besides `self`) and then does an update to `self.salary`. This should not be a setter, but its own method, perhaps:

```
def increment_salary(self):
    self.salary = (1 + self.increment) * self.salary
```

Now, if you did:

```
e1 = Employee("shubh", 10000, 0.1)
print("Old salary: ", e1.salary)
print("Predicted salary: ", e1.salaryafterIncre)
e1.increment_salary()
print("New salary: ", e1.salary)
```

you would obtain the output:

```
10000
11000
11000
```

Is there a particular reason you want to use properties here instead of just variables and methods? Properties are just methods that look like variables.

Comment: Thanks for helping. im what here trying to do is change the value of e1.salary to 11000.

Comment: The code you've written doesn't really make sense for that purpose. In fact, your setter is not a valid setter function: a setter function must take a parameter "value" (as well as "self"). In fact I'd argue what you're doing here probably doesn't need properties at all. I'll elaborate above.